# Android Remove Badge Image Triangle

Tags: android

is there any way to remove corner triangle of `QuickContactBadge` image  ?

XML :

```
        <QuickContactBadge
            android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
setOverlay(null);
```

If you go to QuickContactBadge.java implementation in on draw function you will find :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (!isEnabled()) {
        // not clickable? don't show triangle
        return;
    }

    if (mOverlay == null || mOverlay.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 ||
            mOverlay.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0) {
        // nothing to draw
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

finally just override QuickContactBadge class, but need to draw image in another view

```
public class CustomBadgeImage extends QuickContactBadge {

public CustomBadgeImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomBadgeImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomBadgeImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    return;
}
```

}